# Hair won't follow rig (Blender 2.9)

Tags: rigging, particles, hair

I'm aware this is a recurring question, but having tried the solutions offered in other threads and with no result, I'm going to ask for help:

I got a character, rigged and set up

I got hair particles, which come from the character

My hair particle modifier is AFTER my armature

And yet when I try to pose my characters, only a few strands move with the head. 99% of the hair will just stay floating back.

[image: Before posing]

[image: While posing]

I'm joining my blend file (Blend-exchange seems down, so I couldn't use it, so I used another website), but if anyone has any idea already?

https://gofile.io/d/ip8xrt

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's because of the hair edits. If you delete your hair edits in particle system panel, hair follows head as expected. But of course you loose your edits and that's not what you want. So if you want to keep that hair as particle system (to edit them later or use hair dynamics), I suggest that separate the emitter of the hair from head and parent that plane to head bone. If you don't want to use particle system features, then you can convert hairs in particle system modifier and parent hair object to head bone.

Comment: Uh I'd have never suspected that because in 2.8 when I tried making a similar thing, I didn't have that problem at all? Edited hair still followed posing...

I'll try the parenting trick, and if it work I'll report it here

Comment: So after trying, I realised WHY this happens: When I created a "scalp" to set my hair and parent it, I did so by duplicating some faces from the head. So they still had the vertex groups from the armature. As I removed them I realised the hair were now posing correctly, though the "scalp" wasn't.  

I tried a few more things and realised that the hair follow ALL the vertex groups they're part of, so it fuck things up if your vertexes are in more than one, which is often the case for a character
I'm trying to figure out a clean solution now.